# Can't get .animate() to work w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an overflow div with items hidden. I'd like to scroll the hidden area on click on UP/DOWN elements:

```
$("#up").click(function(){
    $("#container").find(".box:first").animate({"top": "+=20px"}, "slow");
});
$("#down").click(function(){
    $("#container").find(".box:first").animate({"top": "-=20px"}, "slow");
});

<style>
#itemsList {
    height:60px;
}
.box {
    height:20px;
}
</style>

<div id="container">                        
    <div id="up" class="scroll">UP</div>
    <div id="itemsList">
        <div id="item1" class="box">item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="box">qweqweqwe</div>
        <div id="item3" class="box">qqqqqqqq</div>
        <div id="item4" class="box">eeeeeee</div>
        <div id="item5" class="box">rrrrrrrr</div>
        <div id="item6" class="box">tttttt 11</div>
    </div>
    <div id="down" class="scroll">DOWN</div>
</div>
```

Not sure what I'm missing... Here's my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VP5Xb/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd change your jQuery selector from `find('.box:first')` to just `find('.box')`, then simply add `position: relative;` to your `.box` class in CSS.

Comment: Note that that the edit of changing `find('.box:first')` is based on the assumption that you want to slide them ALL, not just the first `.box` element.

Comment: @Neal Thanks. I was so close... Now, after seeing the working example, I've got another quick question. How do I stop scroll, up or down once the last item is reached?

Comment: @santa I'd mark this as answered and open a new question for that

Comment: @beardtwizzle Fair enough. Unfortunately I hit my limit for 6 questions in 24 hours... Can not post another question :(

Comment: That just means there's more excitement for tomorrow! :) it better not to clog up existing questions though